# Show images on native application

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I work with Angular to do a mobile app, and I'm trying to show images on a native application just after take it, in the same method, but now I have to press on a button to show this image.

```
currentImageb: any;

public takePhoto() {
    console.log('Camera Photo Click');
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

    let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

    this.currentImageb = base64Image;

    }, (err) => {
    // Handle error
    });
  }

//Click on Shoh Img Button
  showImgB() {
    (document.getElementById('b') as HTMLImageElement).src = this.currentImageb;
  }
```

```
// I would like to show my image in the <img> without a button
<ion-button (click)="showImgB()">IMAGE id b</ion-button>
<img src="" id="b">
```

I also would like to show each photo I took on my app page, and not just the lastest.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't manipulate the DOM with using for example `getElementById`. Manipulating the DOM should be the last resort in Angular. Usually angular has tools available to do what you want, in this case just apply `src` with the variable, like:

```
<img [src]="currentImageb">
```

Comment: Thanks dude it work like this. Do you know how I can do to show all image a took, because each time a take a new photo the previous picture is replaced by the newest

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. As to your followup question: create an array. Push new images to array and show them in template with *ngFor.